Nodejs USB thermal-printer
I need help configuring my printer for the project. I am working with a Windows system and the connection is via USB. The printer configuration does not find the interface port. Windows does detect the printer and prints the test!!!
In Windows the printer is idle waiting to print
enter image description here
Printer settings to print in my project
enter image description here
I need to print the data that I send to the printer, the problem is that my configuration does not get the port in the interface
